# Setting the ^ Position to an arbitrary column

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am writing a string context macro whose compiler error messages place the ^ in the way you might expect:

In the macro:
`c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, errMsg)`

Console output:

`foo"stuff stuff BROKEN stuff"
 ^`

I would like the little hat ^ to point to a particular place within the string, say:

`foo"stuff stuff BROKEN stuff"
                 ^`

Perusing the various ways to use the Position API, I can easily provide a Position from some existing Tree, but I can't find a way to set an arbitrary position inside a Tree, such as a string literal. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `Tree` and an offset, you can use `withPoint` to calculate the new new `Position`

```
tree.pos.withPoint(tree.pos.start + offset)
```